# what is the meaning of "시" in the below sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 12월 20일까지 3만원 이상 구매 **시** 무료배송

thank you.I don't know how 시 works

Answer (score 1):

시 (時) is a light noun, that literally means time, but is mostly used for conditional conjunction, just like `when` in English. It's usually used in more formal styles often with nominals (but not always). (In Korean, nominalization increases formality in general)

You can also use 때 as a bit less formal alternative when used with regular predicates + `-ㄹ` attbutive ending.

> - 3만원 이상 구매 시 무료배송  Free shipping when spending 30k KRW or more.
> - 응급 시 연락처 Contact number for emergency.
> - 필요할 시에는 추가 요청 바랍니다 Please request for addition when necessary.
> - 필요할 때에는 추가 요청 바랍니다.